# Find Spectral decomposition of $\mathrm{adj}\ A$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

I'm stuck at this question and Don't have any clue how to proceed.

The Spectral decomposition is :

$$A=\sum_{i=1}^k c_iE_i\newcommand{\adj}[1]{\mathrm{adj}\ #1}$$
As we know, the eigenvalues of $\adj{A}$ is $\frac {|A|}{c_1}$, $\ldots$, $\frac {|A|}{c_i}$ (although I don't know how to use it in this question)

I tried using the formula $\adj{A}\cdot A=|A|\cdot I$, Multiplying by $A^{-1}$ from the right and get

$$\adj{A}=|A|\cdot A^{-1} = |A|\cdot(c_1E_1+ ... + c_kE_k)^{-1}$$

And here I'm currently stuck, any hints?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

From "spectral decomposition", I assume that each $E_i$ is a projection onto the eigenspace associated with eigenvalue $c_i$.

It suffices to note that $(c_1 E_1 + \cdots + c_n E_n)^{-1} = c_1^{-1}E_1 + \cdots + c_n^{-1} E_n$. You can verify that this is true by expanding the product
$$
(c_1 E_1 + \cdots + c_n E_n)(c_1^{-1}E_1 + \cdots + c_n^{-1} E_n)
$$
and simplify using the fact that $E_iE_j = 0$ for all $i \neq j$.

Comment: I knew that there is something to do with the power (-1). But I still don't get it , if we multiply $(c_1E_1+ ... + c_nE_n)(c_1^{-1}E_1+ ... + c_n^{-1}E_n$ we get $E_1^2 + E_2^2+....+E_n^2$ we get something different than $I$

Comment: @Roach87 Each $E_i$ is a projection, which means that $E_i^2 = E_i$. Because the projections are part of a spectral decomposition, they add up to the identity matrix